# Ionic2, Content width and height is showing 0

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic2 for a hybrid app. I have a requirement where I need the height + width of Content area (ion-content).

I am trying

`@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
 console.log(this.content.contentWidth,this.content.contentHeight)`

this is giving **0,0**

when I try `console.log(this.content.getContentDimensions());`

It gives

```
{"contentHeight":null,"contentWidth":525,"contentLeft":0,"scrollHeight":1023,"scrollTop":0,"scrollWidth":510,"scrollLeft":0}
```

How can I get ion-content (viewable area) width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("some....",this.content.contentHeight);
            this.contentHeight = this.content.contentHeight;
            console.log("some....",this.contentHeight);
        }, 10);

    }
```